# Spotify Facebook API Documentation

Tags: php, facebook, spotify

I need API/Webservices Documentation to make "playlist" in Spotify via Facebook User Account in Facebook APPs and share it with your friends and the friends can "update" the playlist, but i dont find any documentation to do this, nothing in Facebook and noting in Spotify.

¿Its posible to make this? Where is the documentation for the APP developing in Facebook using the Spotify API?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook APPs and the  Spotify API are two separate entities.  You can however use the two in conjunction.  After creating a facebook application you can communicate with the spotify API just as you would with any other website.  You will not find (at this stage) official documentation on how to use the spotify API within facebook.